# Dealing with missing values in the prediction dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, lightgbm

I am doing prediction using lightgbm with the python package. I have a training dataset and a predict dataset. In the predict dataset, I have nan values for some features. In the results, the prediction is completely wrong when I have nan values. Is there a way to deal with missing values in the predict dataset?

I have tried to use the parameters use_missing and zero_as_missing with all the possibility ((true, false),...) but without success. I am using the master version.

```py
params = {
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'regression',
    'num_leaves': 31,
    'learning_rate': 0.03,
    'max_bin': 255,
    'subsample_for_bin': 50000,
    'min_split_gain': 0.0,
    'min_child_weight': 5,
    'min_child_samples': 10,
    'subsample': 0.5,
    'subsample_freq': 1,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.6,
    'reg_alpha': 0.1,
    'reg_lambda': 1.1,
    'verbose': 0,
    'n_jobs': -1,
    'max_depth': -1,
    'use_missing': False,
    'zero_as_missing': True,
}

gbm = lgb.train(params,
                lgb_train,
               num_boost_round=2000)
y_pred = gbm.predict(predictdata.iloc[:,1:], num_iteration=gbm.best_iteration)
```

I expect that the prediction gives consistent results, but actual results give a prediction too high when there are missing values.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the missing column .you can also predict those missing values by training on test data etc.You can perfrom the imputation techniques esp mode.

Comment: "you can create the missing column":  When I am predicting, the missing value columns are already present.

Comment: "you can also predict those missing values by training on test data etc.You can perfrom the imputation techniques esp mode" : It is already what I am doing currently. But now I was trying to use directly lgbm. My question is: Is LightGBM can deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: This should be in the comment under the question post.